# TypeError: multiple bases have instance layout conflict : langchain library while importing the Pinecone class in a Python 3.8 environment

Tags: langchain

Summary:
I am encountering a "TypeError" with the langchain library while importing the Pinecone class in a Python 3.8 environment on Azure Synapse Studio. The error indicates a layout conflict in the inheritance hierarchy of the langchain library. This issue is impacting the ability to use the library correctly.

Bug Report:

Description:
I am using Azure Synapse Studio with a Python 3.8 environment. In a notebook, I am attempting to import the Pinecone class from the langchain.vectorstores module. Additionally, I am using other modules like OpenAIEmbeddings, datetime, time, csv, openai, requests, pandas, and tiktoken.

Error:
When running the notebook, the following error is raised:

TypeError: multiple bases have instance layout conflict

Steps to Reproduce:

Go to Azure Synapse Studio.
Open a Python notebook.
Select the Pyspark(Python) language for the notebook.
Ensure that the Python version is 3.8.
Execute the following commands to install required packages:

```
!pip install --upgrade pip
!pip install tqdm
!pip install pinecone-client
!pip install typing-extensions==4.5.0
!pip install langchain
!pip install openai
!pip install tiktoken
Execute the following code with imports:
```

```
from langchain.vectorstores import Pinecone
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
import time
import csv

import openai
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, current_timestamp
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType, LongType
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import types as T
import concurrent.futures
import pinecone
import tiktoken
```

Expected Behavior:
The Pinecone class should be successfully imported without any errors.

System Info:

langchain Version: 0.0.249
Python Version: 3.8
Running in Azure Synapse Studio (Notebook)
Other Installed Packages:
[List of installed packages and their versions]

Additional Notes:
The error occurs due to a layout conflict in the inheritance hierarchy of the langchain library. This issue is specific to the library and may require further investigation by the maintainers.